# Laravel - settings depending on environment

Tags: laravel, configuration, laravel-5

I just started using Laravel and now I'm configuring my application. I want different settings for my local and production environment and read the Laravel 5.2 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration) on the best way to do that. But I can't figure out how to do this for all the config files. For example I want the session.secure setting to be `false` on local and `true` on production. What is the best way to do that?

- In the index.php file I do a check `if (App::environment('local'))` and if that is false I update the `session.secure` to `true` -> `config(['session.secure' => true])`.
- I update the `/config/session.php` file and set `'secure' => false` to `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE', false)`. And then I make two .env-files (one for local and one for production) with the variable `SESSION_SECURE` and the corresponding values.
- Is there another/better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to set the settings in your `.env` file. So you change the value of `'secure'` to your `.env` key e.g

```
'secure' => env('SECURE', false),
```

In your .env file on your production server, just set the `.env` value **SECURE** to true.

```
SECURE=true
```

So with this in your local Environment, the `'secure'` setting is set to `false` as default. And if you are on your production Server, just set the `.env` Key to true and the `'secure'` configuration changes also from `false` to `true`.

You may also have a look at this [.env Article for Laravel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-environment-variables)